# Keep intermediate files only on success

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have intermediate files that I want to keep only if they were successfully produced.

Here is my current attempt:

```
all: foo.result

%.result: %.intermediate
        cp $^ $@

%.input:
        touch $@

%.intermediate: %.input
        touch $@
        $(if $(FAIL),exit 1)

.PRECIOUS: %.intermediate
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: %.intermediate

clean:
        rm -f *.intermediate *.input *.result
```

To make it painfully clear what I'm after, run this and try to get no output:

```
(make clean && make foo.result) |&> /dev/null; if [[ ! -e foo.intermediate ]]; then echo "make removed precious intermediate file"; fi; (make clean && make foo.result FAIL=1) |&> /dev/null; if [[ -e foo.intermediate ]]; then echo "make did not remove corrupt file"; fi;
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/27090032/537980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says

> .PRECIOUS The targets which .PRECIOUS depends on are given the
>   following special treatment: if make is killed or interrupted during
>   the execution of their recipes, the target is not deleted. See
>   Interrupting or Killing make. Also, if the target is an intermediate
>   file, it will not be deleted after it is no longer needed, as is
>   normally done. See Chains of Implicit Rules. In this latter respect it
>   overlaps with the .SECONDARY special target.
>
> You can also list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as
>   ‘%.o’) as a prerequisite file of the special target .PRECIOUS to
>   preserve intermediate files created by rules whose target patterns
>   match that file’s name.
>
> .INTERMEDIATE The targets which .INTERMEDIATE depends on are treated
>   as intermediate files. See Chains of Implicit Rules. .INTERMEDIATE
>   with no prerequisites has no effect.
>
> .SECONDARY The targets which .SECONDARY depends on are treated as
>   intermediate files, except that they are never automatically deleted.
>   See Chains of Implicit Rules.
>
> .SECONDARY with no prerequisites causes all targets to be treated as
>   secondary (i.e., no target is removed because it is considered
>   intermediate).

Therefore you should not be using `.PRECIOUS`, you should use `.SECONDARY`. However you can not use a `%` on the right-hand-side of a `.SECONDARY` rule. You could leave it blank (this makes everything secondary), or give a list.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I had missed that `.SECONDARY` doesn't accept `%`. It's good enough for my purposes though.