# Make should not rebuild deep dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a build procedure roughly described by the following Makefile example:

```
a: b
    @echo "Build a, just using b.  Don't care about c."
    touch a

b: c
    @echo "Constructing b from c is cheap..."
    touch b
    @echo "Once accomplished, I no longer need c."

c:
    @echo "Constructing c is very expensive..."
    @echo "Work work work..."
    touch c

clean:
    $(RM) a b c

example: clean
    make a
    $(RM)   c
    make a
```

The point is: I need `c` to build `b`, but once I have `b`, I never again need `c`.  When I do `make example`, `make` makes `c`, `b`, and `a` (as expected), deletes `c`, and then, in the last `make a` invocation, just remakes `c` (and does NOT re-make `b` and `a`, even though, I'd have thought they were stale now).  But, since my goal is `a` and `b` hasn't changed, I don't want to remake `c`.  Forget about it!  Who cares!  `a` should be considered up-to-date.

Another peculiar thing, is that when I

```
make a
rm c
make a
```

(rather than `make example`), in the second invocation `make` rebuilds everything (while in `make example` the second invocation just rebuilds `c`).

How do I prevent `make` from building `c` when its goal is `a` and all of `a`'s immediate prerequisites exist and is fresher than they are (`a` isn't stale compared to `b`), even though the prerequisites of the prerequisites do not?

Edit:  I think that what I may want is to treat *every* file as old (eg. with `--old-file`) *unless that file doesn't exist*.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe for `make example`: after deleting `c`, make rebuilds `c`, `b` and `a`. What version of make do you use?

Comment: GNU Make 3.81 (OS X)

Comment: It does seem that using `GNU Make 4.2.1` differs from 3.81.  When I use 4.2.1 I the second `make a` in `make example` rebuilds everything.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know about this difference between 3.81 and more recent versions.

Comment: Although I have no proof that you are seeing this, note that there HAVE been reports of problems with the MacOS/Xcode-supplied version of GNU make 3.81 which do not appear in the original version of GNU make 3.81, even compiled for MacOS.  And IIRC the failures were very odd.

Comment: OK.  I can settle on 4.2.1.  But that still doesn't solve my problem of deleting c, still having b, and not needing to update a.

Comment: For me, a vanilla (Brew'ed) GNU Make 4.2.1 on macOS rebuilt only `c`, just  like the Apple-supplied 3.81. What I think you're seeing here is that the (older) Apple filesystem only tracks the timestamps with 1-second resolution, so the existing `b` and `a` have the same timestamp as the rebuilt `c`. With `sleep 1` added after all the `touch` commands in the Makefile, both Make versions rebuilt `c`, `b`, `a` as expected on macOS.

Comment: @JohnMarshall, very interesting---and you're right!  Adding a bunch of `sleep`s in there prevents that unusual behavior.  It still doesn't help me not rebuild a when c is gone, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want `make` to treat the file `c` as an intermediate file, a file that does not have any importance to you other than as an intermediate result when generating another file or other files. This concept is explained in section [10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) of the manual. Since your example does not use any implicit rules, you can manually mark your file `c` as [`.INTERMEDIATE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets).

This makefile shows `c` as an intermediate file.

```
a: b
        @echo "Build a, just using b.  Dont care about c."
        touch a

b: c
        @echo "Constructing b from c is cheap..."
        touch b
        @echo "Once accomplished, I no longer need c."

c: d
        @echo "Constructing c is very expensive..."
        @echo "Work work work..."
        touch c

.INTERMEDIATE: c
.PRECIOUS: c
```

I added a file `d`, based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855248/make-should-not-rebuild-deep-dependencies#comment94585951_53867713), although it is not needed for this example to work.

Before invoking `make`, the file `d` has to exist, it is the starting point of the chain. When invoking `make`, the following happens:

```
$ touch d
$ make
Constructing c is very expensive...
Work work work...
touch c
Constructing b from c is cheap...
touch b
Once accomplished, I no longer need c.
Build a, just using b.  Dont care about c.
touch a
```

Now deleting `c` will not have any impact on the build:

```
$ rm c
$ make
make: `a' is up to date.
```

Other than that, the update behavior based on dependencies is "the same as usual".

The [`.PRECIOUS` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets) is optional. It is a built-in that instructs `make` not to delete the intermediate file named `c`. You can see for yourself what happens if you remove that line.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `.INTERMEDIATE`.  Can you explain the difference between `.INTERMEDIATE` and `.SECONDARY`?

Comment: I never use `.SECONDARY` but it looks like it does the same thing as `.INTERMEDIATE` AND it does not throw away your intermediate file. So it looks you could use that as well in stead of both `.INTERMEDIATE` and `.PRECIOUS`. To me, the names of the latter two make it more clear what they are intended to do, but that is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more: it is not typical to have to mark a file as `.INTERMEDIATE` explicitly. Usually files are intermediate because of the implicit chaining as explained in section 10.4. The `.PRECIOUS` indication is common though. That is why I ended up using those two explicitly and why I was less familiar with `.SECONDARY`. Of course, if you do not *want* to keep `c` around in the first place, then just using `.INTERMEDIATE` is sufficient and `make` will delete `c` by itself.

Comment: OK.  So, if I don't want c to be automatically deleted I can mark it (`.INTERMEDIATE` and `.PRECIOUS`) or `.SECONDARY`, as these are equivalent?  If they're equivalent, why have a `.SECONDARY` target?

Comment: The documentation of `.PRECIOUS` does indicate that there is an overlap with `.SECONDARY`. The difference seems to be the resulting behavior when make gets a fatal signal while a shell is executing, see [5.6 Interrupting or Killing make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Interrupts).

Comment: Also, you can not list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as `%.o`) as a prerequisite file of `.SECONDARY`. See [Why .SECONDARY does not work with patterns (%) while .PRECIOUS does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090032/why-secondary-does-not-work-with-patterns-while-precious-does). Apparently getting rid of that difference has been a to-do for many years.

Answer (score 0):

`b` might be built from `c`, but you don't want to tell Make that `b` depends on `c` — if `b` merely exists, then that's good enough. So you might write `b`'s recipe as

```
b:
    $(MAKE) c
    @echo "Constructing b from c is cheap..."
    touch b
    @echo "Once accomplished, I no longer need c."
```

or if `c` is **only** used in making `b`, you could just fold the commands for making `c` into the recipe for `b` and not expose the existence of `c` to Make at all.

Maybe there are more elegant ways of expressing this, without invoking sub-makes. And if `c` has some prerequisites that would cause it to be rebuilt if they were updated, I guess they would need to be listed as reprequisites of `b` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my real example I have multiple things that might depend on c, not just b.  Once those things are there, c can be tossed.  c also does have prerequisites which, if they change, c changes (and what depends on c changes).  But if c is deleted and you've already got the things that depend on it, no problem.